# Connecting my calendar (s) to Google mini?

Tags: google-calendar

∆ Huawei p20 lite nova e
∆ Bundled calendar
∆ Google calendar which is set default
∆ Calendar Widget (have given access to G)

I ask my Google mini to tell me what's on my calendar or read out my agenda and it just says I'm sorry I don't understand or something like that and I've looked on a couple of websites and they all have this step-by-step that seems really outdated because my Google activity page looks very different I'm assuming it's the latest.

so folks I would like to have access to my calendar while talking to Google mini home which is a set on the same wifi and and I've tried it with VPN on and off and it still the same.

So there's no confusion I'm asking Google mini to read my calendar which it doesn't.
Thanks

Comment: If your calendar events are in Google Calendar (not via some third-party connector), you are using a regular Gmail account (not G-Suite), granted all the Google action permissions, and in a supported country/language, getting voice commands on Android or Google mini should work. The wording about how your "bundled" calendar is configured is unclear.

Comment: @MorrisonChang ok that seems to be working fine now except it won't read me my full agenda all the way to September eccetera any ideas